# Windows scales apps however it wants regardless its High DPI settings

Tags: windows-10, 4k-resolution, high-dpi

As I have a 4K screen, Windows suggested to use 150% scaling which is just fine otherwise things are so small that it's barely readable.

So far so good, but now I have the following hapenning randomly:

- sometimes Windows decides to honor this setting
- sometimes Windows decides to not honor this setting

Basically, let's say that VLC may be shown at the right upscaling (150%) but sometimes it isn't (100%), it just seems to depend on the humor Windows is after a reboot, some days it's fine, some days it's not.

Note that I haven't changed the per-application High DPI settings:

[image]

Also it does not happen only for VLC but also a few other apps which all use the default setting.

Any ideas ?

Comment: not all applications are "high-dpi aware", but I think there is a "dpi awareness" column you can add to the task manager "details" tab which might help you figure out what to do with individual applications

Comment: Good to know, checking that out !